# Migrate Sybase SQL Server/11.0.3.2 ( Sybase 11) to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, sybase, migrate

I would like to migrate 3 databases of Sybase SQL Server 11.0.3.2 instance (Sybase 11) to SQL Server 2008.

I know that i can SSMA between Sybase 11.9.2 or more to SQL Server 2008. Then i have only one problem, migrate Sybase 11.0 to Sybase 11.9.2

I try dump between Sybase 11.0 to Sybase 12.5.4, not work. (i haven't Sybase 11.9 Server).
ddlgen don't work on Sybase 11.0.
The only solution that i found is to use system table and bcp...

An other solution is upgrade server to SQL server 11 to ASE 12.0 and then SSMA database to SQL SERVER 2008. It's the only "simple" way ? (I have many database that i don't want migrate to Sybase 11.9 or more)

There is an other simple way to do that ?

Thank you

Comment: You are talking about two different Sybase product lines that have completely different upgrade paths.  SQL Anywhere 11 IS NOT Sybase 11.  Sybase 11 was an ASE release back in the 1990's.  ddlgen is a Sybase ASE tool, not a SQL Anywhere tool.  What are you currently running?  SQL Anywhere or Sybase ASE?

Comment: Thank michael, Select @@version return SQL Server/11.0.3.2

Comment: Ok, so you are using ASE (SQL Server), not SQL Anywhere.

Comment: @MichaelGardner Ok thank, so, do you have a way to migrate ASE 11.0 to ASE 11.9 ?

Comment: Sorry, I threw my 11.9.2 documentation out 10 years ago.